# Infinity nodeJS get/post request

Tags: node.js, api

So I'm trying to learn nodeJS.. But something wierd is happening. When I try to make a GET or a POST request it keep requesting infinitly on the localhost. I tested with a simple piece of code just requesting a simple Hello Word but it still doesnt works. It was working perfectly yesterday.
I tested insomnia, postman and the browser. If someone can help me would be very nice, cause I'm really stucked here...[printscream of the insomnia infinity request](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jhI6H.png)

```
const {json} = require('express');
const express = require('express');
const {uuid} = require('uuidv4'); 

const app = express();

app.use(express,json);

const projects = [];

app.get('/projects', (request, response) => {
    return response.json(projects);         
});

app.post('/projects', (request, response) => {
    const {title, owner} = request.body;

    const project = {id: uuid(), title, owner };

    projects.push(project);

    return response.json(project);         
});

app.listen(3333, () => {
    console.log('Working ')
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's just two little mistakes. Take in mind that express.json() is a method, so you need to put it like this:

```
app.use(express.json())
```

You are using a comma instead of a point. However, you have done a destructuring of the .json () method; therefore, you do not have to prepend express; it would look like this:

```
app.use(json())
```

On the other hand, you probably have an unwanted result in the post request since you send the **project** variable instead of **projects**. Be sure that is what you want.

Comment: Wow It worked, thank you so much!! And Yes, I want the project variable cause I want to make a list of projects... But it apparently doesnt change the results if I send one or other.